# Call F# function that has a function parameter from C#

Tags: c#, f#

In F# i have the function:

```ml
module ModuleName
let X (y: int -> unit) = ()
```

How can i call this in C#? Ideally it would look like

```cs
ModuleName.X(x => x*x);
```

But this lambda syntax does not convert implicitly to a FSharpFunc.

Comment: Does this help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2010/07/27/converting-system-func-lt-t1-tn-gt-to-fsharpfunc-lt-t-tresult-gt.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to expose your API using standard .NET delegate types.  In this case, that means that your F# definition should look more like:

```ml
let X (y:Action<int>) = ()
```

However, if you want to keep your F# API the same as it currently is, then you could use [`FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370396.aspx) from the C# side:

```cs
ModuleName.X(FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc(x => x*x));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using the static FSharpFunc.FromConverter method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353520.aspx

```
ModuleName.X(FSharpFunc.FromConverter(x => x*x));
```

EDIT: I just noticed that your function calls for an `int -> unit` but your call specifies an `int -> int`.  To create an FSharpFunc that returns unit, you can use one of the static methods of the `FuncConvert` static class.